# Is getting list of all mails supported with personal account in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have created an app in Azure Portal and granted permissions to read user data and user mail. But I get 401 Unauthorized error when trying to get list of mails.

According to [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions), The permissions I need for application are : Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite. I granted all these but still get the error.

In the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#permissions), it's not mentioned whether personal account is supported for this or not in application type permission.

```
/// get access token
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/");

var stringContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", ClientID),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", ClientSecret),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
});

var response = httpClient.PostAsync(TenantID + "/oauth2/v2.0/token", stringContent).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var auth_res_json = JObject.Parse(response);
var token = auth_res_json["access_token"].ToString();


/// now read user data
HttpClient httpClient2 = new HttpClient();
httpClient2.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/");

httpClient2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
var response2 = httpClient2.GetAsync("users/" + UserID + "/messages").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var mails = JObject.Parse(response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

Note that I get the access token properly, no problem with that.
Also, I can get the user data by using `httpClient2.GetAsync("users/" + UserID)` properly, no error there too and the results are good.

The permissions I granted are these:

[image]

The added scopes are:

[image]

And I added these scopes to my application:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Application permissions are consented by the admin for the whole tenant he/she is part of.
Microsoft accounts are not part of a tenant, and as far as I know they don't have a way to consent to application permissions for their sole account.
On top of that when you call the token endpoint, you're providing the tenant ID and not common, this tells the endpoint to only generate tokens valid for this tenant.
You should switch to delegated permissions and depending on what you are building implement the device code flow (native apps) or the on behalf flow (APIs).
Lastly you should look into MSAL and the Microsoft graph SDK librairies, it'll save you a lot of time in implementation.